# Sql Server 2008: Strange error in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to run the following sql server stored procedure, and I am unable to get it to execute. The procedure query is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_StockNavigationReportData]
    @startDate VARCHAR(200),
    @endDate VARCHAR(200),
    @groupBy VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT M.VRNOA, M.VRDATE 'DATE', M.REMARKS, D.qty 'QTY', g2.name 'Godown_2', g.name 'Godown_1'
    FROM 
        Stockmain M, StockDetail D, GODOWN G,   (
            SELECT * FROM GODOWN
        ) AS g2
    WHERE 
            M.Etype='navigation' 
        AND M.STID = D.STID
        AND D.GODOWN_ID = G.GODOWN_ID 
        AND g2.godown_id = D.GODOWN_ID2
        AND VRDATE  BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(@startDate AS DATETIME),101)
        AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(@endDate AS DATETIME), 101)   
    ORDER BY 
        @groupBy ASC
END
```

And the error that I get is:

> Msg 1008, Level 16, State 1, Procedure get_StockNavigationReportData, Line 25
>   The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a variable as part of the expression identifying a column position. Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing a column name.

Can anybody please have a look and tell me what I am doing wrong here + How may I get this to work?

Comment: You cannot order by a parameter value,u need to do with column name..

Comment: What you need is [Dynamic ORDER BY](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-order-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you cannot use variable in the order by clause which specify order position. 
http://exacthelp.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-use-variable-in-order-by-clause.html

You should write something like this:

```
ORDER BY 
        CASE 
WHEN @groupBy = 1 THEN VRNOA
WHEN @groupBy = 2 THEN DATE
WHEN @groupBy = 3 THEN REMARKS
...............
............
END
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use a variable in the `order by` clause.  Instead, you have to do something like:

```
order by (case when @groupBy = 'VRNOA' then VRNOA
               . . .
          end)
```

Be careful, though, because if the columns are of different types, either unexpected things might happen or might get another error.  (There is an alternative to use dynamic SQL, but I would not recommend that.)

Also, the name `@groupby` is a bit misleading.  "Grouping" is a SQL term equivalent to "aggregation".  Wouldn't `@OrderBy` or `@SortBy` be more appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

You can't order by a variable that way.

If you want to do that, build a dynamic query string, then execute it.

Something like:

```
declare @sql varchar(4000)

set @sql = 'select * from tablename order by ' + @orderbyclause + ' ASC'
exec (@sql)
```