# SQL Server 2016 Upgrade Advisor Issue

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2016 Upgrade Advisor reports a database compatibility issue:
Rule: Constant expressions are not allowed in the ORDER BY clause in 90 or later compatibility modes.

Version90
Rule Title: Constant expressions are not allowed in the ORDER BY clause in 90 or later compatibility modes

Recommendation: Before you change the database compatibility mode to 90 or later, modify statements that use constant expressions in the ORDER BY clause to use a column name or column alias, or a nonnegative integer representing the position of the name or alias in the select list.

Rule ID: Microsoft.Rules.Data.Upgrade.UR00326

This is the SQL that's causing the error and I cannot figure out how to change the Order By statement to satisfy the upgrade advisor???

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [Utilities].[GetProcStats] (@order varchar(100) = 'use')
AS
BEGIN
WITH GetQueryStats
( plan_handle,
  total_elapsed_time,
  total_logical_reads,
  total_logical_writes,
  total_physical_reads )
AS
( SELECT qs.plan_handle,
     SUM(qs.total_elapsed_time)   AS total_elapsed_time,
     SUM(qs.total_logical_reads)  AS total_logical_reads,
     SUM(qs.total_logical_writes) AS total_logical_writes,
     SUM(qs.total_physical_reads) AS total_physical_reads
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
   GROUP BY qs.plan_handle )
SELECT DB_NAME(st.dbid) AS database_name,
       OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) AS schema_name,
       OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid) AS proc_name,
       SUM(cp.usecounts) AS use_counts,
       SUM(cp.size_in_bytes) AS size_in_bytes,
       SUM(qs.total_elapsed_time) AS total_elapsed_time,
      CAST( SUM(qs.total_elapsed_time) AS decimal(38, 4)) / SUM(cp.usecounts) AS avg_elapsed_time_per_use,
       SUM(qs.total_logical_reads) AS total_logical_reads,
      CAST(SUM(qs.total_logical_reads) AS decimal(38, 4)) / SUM(cp.usecounts) AS avg_logical_reads_per_use,
       SUM(qs.total_logical_writes) AS total_logical_writes,
      CAST(SUM(qs.total_logical_writes) AS decimal(38, 4)) / SUM(cp.usecounts) AS avg_logical_writes_per_use,
       SUM(qs.total_physical_reads) AS total_physical_reads,
      CAST(SUM(qs.total_physical_reads) AS decimal(38, 4)) / SUM(cp.usecounts) AS avg_physical_reads_per_use,
      st.text
  FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
   INNER JOIN GetQueryStats qs ON cp.plan_handle = qs.plan_handle
   INNER JOIN sys.procedures p ON st.objectid = p.object_id
  WHERE p.type IN ('P', 'PC')
  GROUP BY st.dbid, st.objectid, st.text
  ORDER BY
     CASE @order
       WHEN 'name' THEN OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid)
       WHEN 'size' THEN SUM(cp.size_in_bytes)
       WHEN 'read' THEN SUM(qs.total_logical_reads)
       WHEN 'write' THEN SUM(qs.total_logical_writes)
     ELSE SUM(cp.usecounts)
END DESC;
END;
```

I tried changing the ORDER BY to the following based on the suggestion.

ORDER BY
     CASE 
       WHEN @order = 'name'  THEN OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid, st.dbid)
       WHEN @order = 'size'  THEN SUM(cp.size_in_bytes)
       WHEN @order = 'read'  THEN SUM(qs.total_logical_reads)
       WHEN @order = 'write' THEN SUM(qs.total_logical_writes)
     ELSE SUM(cp.usecounts)
END DESC;

But the SQL Server 2016 Upgrade Advisor still reports the same issue.

Comment: I am having the same problem as well. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable in the Order By clause anymore.

[Sql Server 2008: Strange error in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827458/sql-server-2008-strange-error-in-stored-procedure)

has a possible solution

Comment: Can you remove some of your options, there are many things that could go wrong here. First try just simple fieldnames. Once that works add back in the sum(fieldname), finally add back in schema_name which is the label, rather than the Object_Name(xxx)